# WinDBG extension - Breakpoint listing

Tags: c, windbg, breakpoints

Is there any way how can I get a list of breakpoints from within Windows Debugger Extension?

I'm using plain C (and I'm trying to avoid using COM interface they provide and I'm not even sure if that COM interface provides a way to do that).

I've read  and researched `wdbgexts.h` and `dbghelp.h` but neither of them seem to contain any usable function or global variable, although there are some info on BPs in those files, such as `DBGKD_GET_VERSION::BreakpointWithStatus`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Debugger Extension provides function `ULONG64 GetExpression(PCSTR lpExpression)` (of course it's *<sarcasm>well documented</sarcasm>*)

```
#define GetExpression    (ExtensionApis.lpGetExpressionRoutine)
```

which allows you to get results from any WinDBG expression like `?? @eip`.

```
GetExpression( "@eip"); // Without `?? ` in the beginning
```

Next, if you take a look at:
Windows Debugger Help **»** Debugging Tools For Windows **»** Debuggers **»** Debugger References **»** Debugger Commands **»** Syntax Rules **»** Pseudo-Registers Syntax

You will find a line what looks like this:

> **$bp***Number* - The address of the corresponding breakpoint. For example,
>   $bp3 (or $bp03) refers to the breakpoint whose breakpoint ID is 3.
>   Number is always a decimal number. If no breakpoint has an ID of
>   Number, $bpNumber evaluates to zero. For more information about
>   breakpoints, see Using Breakpoints.

So with some overhead you'll get this (working) solution:

```
#define MAX_BREAKPOINTS 100

DWORD i, addr;
CHAR buffer[] = "$bp\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";

for( i = 0; i < MAX_BREAKPOINTS; ++i){
    // Appends string to BP prefix
    itoa( i, buffer+3, 10);
    addr = GetExpression( buffer);
    if( !addr){
        break;
    }

    // Do stuff
}
```

The only another solution is to use COM objects as Steve Johnson suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Use IDebugControl::GetNumberBreakpoints, then IDebugControl::GetBreakpointByIndex.

Comment: I see that you're trying to avoid the COM interfaces.  I don't think that's necessary, even from C.  In any case, I don't know of another way to do this.

Comment: I found a clumsy way to do this without COM (see my answer), unfortunately we have strict "plain C policy" for this project and I really don't feel like implementing crazy things like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C)